# noun-pronoun agreement

Tags: nouns, pronouns, agreement, antecedents, pronominal-agreement

> Like the planets, the stars are in motion, some of them at tremendous
>   speeds, but **they**...

Just based on the above, how can we tell which noun the pronoun *they* refers to: planets or stars? Is there any rule to determine which is which?

The sentence finishes like this:

> ...are so far away from earth that their apparent
>   positions in the sky do not change enough for their movement to be
>   observed during a single human existence

I know that 'intuitively' you can 100% say that *they* refers to stars. But, for example, if you replace planets with X and stars with Y, how can you decide what *they* refers to?

Comment: Context is everything: "Like the planets, the stars are in motion, some of them at tremendous speeds, but they are not relativistic."

Comment: Here is the full sentence.... but they are so far away from earth that their apparent positions in the sky do not change enough for their movement to be observed during a single human existence.

Comment: I know that 'intuitively' you can 100% say that 'they' refers to stars. But, for example, if you replace planets with X and stars with Y, how can you decide what 'they' refers to ?

Answer (score 3):

The 'rule' is that you go left until you find the first antecedent that works. In your example that would be stars.

This is not particularly intuitive. The type of pronoun limits its antecedents. A personal pronoun, for example, must refer to a person, so in a sentence like "*Mary went to the shop she had noticed the day before*", 'she' cannot refer to the shop so you keep keep going left until you find a person - Mary. Compare with "*Mary went to the shop, but it had closed*" where the third-person pronoun 'it' can refer to the first noun you meet - shop, and would be inappropriate for 'Mary'.

It does not always hinge on the type of pronoun. Sometimes you have to draw on encyclopaedic knowledge, as in the [Winograd Schema Challenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winograd_Schema_Challenge) which uses two sentences such as "*The city councilmen refused the demonstrators a permit because they feared violence*" and "*The city councilmen refused the demonstrators a permit because they advocated violence*", where knowing how councilmen and protesters behave is needed to decide on which one is the antecedent for 'they'.

Comment: The last paragraph is the point. The answer to the question is "No, there is not a rule". There are heuristics, some syntactic, some grammatical, and some depending on real-world knowledge. And sometimes it remains stubbornly ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

**They** here refers to stars.
Keep in mind that **planets** is not the subject of the sentence before *"but"* here.
**the stars are in motion, some of them at tremendous speeds**<- This sentence fixes our focus on **stars**,not **stars and planets**.

Answer (score 0):

Referring the full sentence as

> Like the planets, the stars are in motion, some of them at tremendous
>   speeds, but they are not relativistic.

I would like to say that here the pronoun **they** has been used to refer both the stars and the planet bcz here the writer is comparing stars and planets and not only the stars we can see the in beginning of sentence.And there is no such predefined rule to decide that but we need to understand it by context of the sentence.

Comment: You are referring to my conjectured complete sentence, which I wrote (and you referenced) before sumelic edited the OP to give us the original complete sentence.  You are right that we must understand the antecedent by context, and the context here is that *they* is modified by *relativistic*.  Only speeds in this sentence can be relativistic, so the antecedent for *they* must be *speeds*.  In the proper sentence, planets do change their apparent position in the sky as seen from earth, so the antecedent for *they* must be *stars*.

Comment: I am aware of that sir and that's the only reason I've mentioned the referred sentence.The reference of pronoun **they** depends on the whole sentence only.It may vary with the sentence all depends on context.

Comment: I'm sorry if I've merely told you something you already know.  You wrote "I would like to say that here the pronoun **they** has been used to refer [to] both the stars and planets...."  But "stars and planets" is not a possible antecedent for *they* in this sentence because whatever "they" is, they must be "relativistic," and as I wrote the sentence the only candidate is "speeds."

Comment: Yes sir, you are right, I agree.But still if we take another example there might be change of antecedent.

Comment: Absolutely.  To see that, we just have to check the actual complete sentence rather than the one I made up.  As I'm fond of saying, the grammar by itself can only take you so far.

Comment: Yeah truly said.Thumbs up for it.

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb for writers is that, if you have to ask that question, you should rewrite the sentence to resolve the ambiguity, such as by changing "they" to "the stars." That's the rule even if the rewritten sentence seems less elegant.

Here, however, *they* refers to *stars* because *they* refers to the pronoun *them* in the preceding parenthetical expression, and *them* clearly refers to *stars*. By contrast, the phrase "Like the planets" is an adverbial phrase which modifies "the stars are in motion" and which is not connected grammatically to the rest of the sentence, except through the phrase "the stars are in motion."

Comment: Thank you very much.'Them-They' correlation is very apt and cleared my confusion.